# How to remove the message header informations in WebSphere MQ grouped message while receving in .Net client

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

I am trying to recevie logically grouped messages from an remote MQ using .Net client using native api [amqmdnet - WebSphere MQ Classes for .NET], which was put by java client using native api.

While we are getting the logically grouped messages we are seeing some header information in all the messages in that group which will be showing differently in each editors, [notepad++, editplus etc.]

The below specified header information's is appended in every logical message in that group something like "MDE "

We are using the `getmessageoptions`, `openoptions` as below,

```
mintMQQueueOpenOptions = IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED + IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
mobjMQGetMessageOptions = New MQGetMessageOptions
mobjMQGetMessageOptions.Options = IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQGMO_NO_SYNCPOINT +  IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
'mobjMQGetMessageOptions.Options = mobjMQGetMessageOptions.Options + MQC.MQGMO_LOGICAL_ORDER  'Or MQC.MQGMO_ALL_MSGS_AVAILABLE
```

Code snippet to read the all the logical message in that group,

```
            '=================================
            ' INTANTIATE THE MQ MESSAGE OBJECT
            objMQMessage = New MQMessage
            objMQMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING
            '=================================
            ' CLEAR THE MESSAGE VARIABLE
            strMQMessage = ""

            Do
                '============================
                ' GET THE MESSAGE FROM THE MQ
                mobjMQQueue.Get(objMQMessage, mobjMQGetMessageOptions)

                '============================
                ' READ THROUGH THE MESSAGE
                strMQMessage += objMQMessage.ReadString(objMQMessage.MessageLength)

                '============================
                ' SET GMO.MATCHOPTIONS TO GROUP ID, INITIALLY IT WAS SET TO "MQC.MQMO_NONE"                            
                mobjMQGetMessageOptions.MatchOptions = MQC.MQMO_MATCH_GROUP_ID

                '============================
                ' DO UNTIL - MESSAGE IS THE LAST IN THE GROUP OR THE GROUP CONSISTS OF ONLY ONE MESSAGE.
            Loop While (mobjMQGetMessageOptions.GroupStatus <> MQC.MQGS_LAST_MSG_IN_GROUP)

            '====================================
            ' COLLECT THE MESSAGE IN AN ARRAYLIST
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strMQMessage) Then objMQMessageList.Add(strMQMessage)

            '============================
            ' COMMIT THE FETCH OPERATION
            mobjMQQueueManager.Commit()
```

How we can remove this header information from each message?

Answer (score 2):

The `MQMDE` contains MQMD fields that exist in the version-2 MQMD, but not in the version-1 MQMD.  The Infocenter topic [*Overview for MQMD*](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q097400_.htm) describes how the `MQMD` version affects behavior of the GET call:

> On the MQGET call, if the application provides a version-1 MQMD, the
>   queue manager prefixes the message returned with an MQMDE, but only if
>   one or more of the fields in the MQMDE has a non-default value. The
>   Format field in MQMD will have the value MQFMT_MD_EXTENSION to
>   indicate that an MQMDE is present.

Based on this, I would suggest providing a Version 2 `MQMD`.  Perhaps this will solve the problem:

```
            '=================================
            ' INTANTIATE THE MQ MESSAGE OBJECT
            objMQMessage = New MQMessage
            objMQMessage.Version = 2
            objMQMessage.Format  = MQC.MQFMT_STRING
            '=================================
```

Since the `objMQMessage` is reused for successive calls, you may need to set the version before each GET.

The IBM MQ Knowledge Center page "[MQMDE - Message descriptor extension > Overview for MQMDE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q097790_.htm)" also has some useful information on the topic:

> **Usage:** Applications that use a version-2 MQMD will not encounter an MQMDE structure. However, specialized applications, and
>   applications that continue to use a version-1 MQMD, might encounter an
>   MQMDE in some situations. The MQMDE structure can occur in the
>   following circumstances:
>
> - Specified on the MQPUT and MQPUT1 calls
> - Returned by the MQGET call
> - In messages on transmission queues